# Does League of Legends have a tournament that is recognized as the 'Most Important'?

Tags: league-of-legends, competitive-gaming

Is there a tournament that is comparable to the Super Bowl, World Series, Stanley Cup Playoffs, FIFA World Cup, Daytona 500, etc.? Or does LoL not have seasons in the traditional sense of other sports. I ask this because it says that the game is in Season 2 so I'm curious.

Is there an all-defining championship for LoL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have a championship at the end of every season. Last year the season 1 championship was the dreamhack tournament which was won by Fnatic, but we don't know when or where the season 2 championship will take place yet.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am answering this correctly, but I know at the end of this season there will be a tournament for **2 million dollars**

source:

http://competitive.euw.leagueoflegends.com/competitive/season-2/introduction